# Why I am coming across "Format Exception" while execution in C# TCP/IP Application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

The code is as follows:

The ServerForm Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SimpleTCP;

namespace TCPIP
{
public partial class ServerForm : Form
{
    public ServerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SimpleTcpServer server;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = new SimpleTcpServer();
        server.Delimiter = 0x13;    //enter
        server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;

    }

    private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
    {
        StatusText.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
        {
            StatusText.Text = e.MessageString;
            e.ReplyLine(string.Format("You said: {0}",e.MessageString));
        });
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StatusText.Text += "Server Starting !";
        System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(HostText.Text)); //error here
        server.Start(ip,Convert.ToInt32(PortText.Text));
    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(server.IsStarted)
        {
            server.Stop();
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Code of the ClientForm is as follows:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpClient client;
        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            StatusText.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                StatusText.Text = e.MessageString;
                //...
            });
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.WriteLineAndGetReply(TextMessage.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
        }
    }
}
```

The issue in the above code is that it is 'build'ing correctly and even when I am debug it with the new instance, the code is running fine, but will I debug, as soon as I press the "start" button in the Server form it shows the error in line :

```
System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(HostText.Text));
```

The error is: **System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'**

Please refer the Screenshot for details and suggest a potential fix to the issue.[Image of Screenshot of Error inLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ0ta.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and post a [mcve]. There's too much irrelevant code here

Comment: The code above is of the two forms application, I think it is important to get through the code completely, for reference since it is creating the problem as a whole

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is right here, really too much irrilevant code here. ask yourself "what is causing my error?" you already have identified the line raising the error: is the rest of the code related to the error? (spoiler: no)

Comment: @DevBhatnagar: You can reproduce the error itself with a simple call to `long.Parse` with bad input. If you're wondering *why* you end up with incorrect input, you need to provide a different set of information than what you've provided.

Comment: Thanks Thanks @GlanPaolo I got the point now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly `HostText.Text` is returning a value that can't be parsed into a `long`.

This exception is coming from `long.Parse`, which is really a language shortcut for [`Int64.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b6b4bx3(v=vs.110).aspx), whose documentation states that it will throw this exception if the input string is not formatted correctly.

Comment: I went through the documentation, can there be any alternative fix to avoid the exception?

Comment: @DevBhatnagar Sure, use `long.TryParse`

Comment: Hey what if `HostText.Text` is given an initial value? @CamiloTerevinto?

Comment: You are handling a value inserted by user. he should type some text value that can be converted to a number, but he can type "abc" as well: your code should check if the input from user is correct before proceeding. If not, warn your user "please insert a numeric value"

Comment: Which two arguments I should use in `long.TryParse()` in context to the code of my application?

Comment: @DevBhatnagar: It depends more on your actual requirements than on the code you've provided. What would you expect to have happen if an invalid number was entered? Also: why are you expecting the user to enter an IP Address as a `long` value: should you be using `IPAddress.Parse` (or `.TryParse`) directly, rather than converting the input to a `long` first? Why are you even requiring the user to enter an IP address? Do you really intend to filter incoming requests so they're only serviced if they're directed to the given IP Address?

Comment: Yes I really intend to filter the incoming requests.

Comment: And how do you intend for users to enter the IP address?